# Internal Tag Parsing in Ghost

Tags: ghost-blog

Within ghost if I use the following to display all internal tags,

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    {{#foreach tags visibility="internal"}}
        {{name}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

How do I display a tag that has a certain string and then string off the beginning. 
i.e I want to add an internal tag of:
`#META:Cisco / ASA / 8.2.1`
But to print `Cisco / ASA / 8.2.1` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. :)

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this simply using the built-in features, but you 
can create a custom app that registers a custom helper that can do this. 
Here's how to do that:

1. Install the ghost-app package to your Ghost installation
2. Check out the [docs](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Apps-Getting-Started-for-Ghost-Devs) on how to create an app.
3. Create the app. :)
4. Modify gscan to recognize your helper.

Since I found your question interesting, I implemented this app myself. You can view and download the source code from here: https://github.com/conwid/RemovesubstringApp

I also wrote a little blog post about how I created it and how you can set it up and modify gscan in detail here: https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-creating-custom-ghost-helpers-using-apps/

With my version, you'll be able to write this in your templates:

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    {{#foreach tags visibility="internal"}}
        {{removeSubstring name '#META:'}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Hope this helps, if you have problems with the implementation or the setup, feel free to ask.